# Loopback timeout(no response from server) when make a time consume request

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback, angular-loopback

I have a request which processes thousands of data. So sometimes It takes more then 5 minutes to complete.

But unfortunately loopback returns timeout(no response from server) before process is completed.

In nodejs request. You can remove request timeout for specific request by below code.

```
request.setTimeout(0)
```

Can anyone tell me how can i do this for loopback **remote method**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was quite easy then it looked like.

All i had to do is pass `http req object` in my remote method and then set timeout to 0.

```
 Visit.remoteMethod(
        'caculateDistance',
        {
            description: 'Calculate distance from beacon using rssi',
            accepts: [
                { arg: "req", type: "object", http: { source: "req" } },
                { arg: 'activationId', type: 'string', required: true }
            returns: { arg: 'data', type: 'Object', root: true },
            http: { verb: 'patch', path: '/:activationId/calculate-distance' },
        }
    );


Visit.caculateDistance = function (httpReq, activationId, callbackFn) {
        httpReq.setTimeout(0);
        /////calculations....
});
```

Thanks anyway!

Comment: didn't work ... still crashes on 50000 ms !!

Answer (score 5):

I am not quite sure of this but you can give it a try as i feel this might work

You can create a interceptor for that particular route or all the routes in the `server.js` file.

```
app.all('/api/*', function(req, res, next){
    request.setTimeout(0); // this is the statement and pass it to the next middle ware func.
    next();
});
```

> If not you can also use a remote method for that route and add the
>   same there.

**Update**

If you want it for a single api just use

```
app.all('<exact api path>', function(req, res, next){
    request.setTimeout(0); // this is the statement and pass it to the next middle ware func.
    next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but i need ti for only one api. It should not  affect any other.

Comment: @AnkurAkvaliya then you can just go in the remote method of the same of best of in the `app.all('pass your api path')` this will work for that api only